# Auto Complete mask on Android EditTextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I need to get an approach. Please help me out.

I am developing an app where I need to get price as input from user. There I need EditTextView with autocomplete mask.

Like if user wish to type 100500, there will be automatically a string replaced with input value, which is $100,500.00

I think this is enough to explain what actually I need. Please suggest me on this. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a TextWatcher on your EditText like below. In the onTextChanged method you will want to analyse and modify the users current input (in CharSequence) and then update your EditText (text.setText("yourModifiedText"))

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
text.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, intcount, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
          int count) {

  }
}
```